# Why am I unable to read my new text file?

Tags: python

I am able to rewrite a file with my corrections, but I am not able to read the newly made text file. Whats going on?

```
with open('email_1.txt') as email_1:
    new_email = open('new_email.txt', 'w')
    for line in email_1:
        new_email.write(line.replace('apple', 'turnip'))

with open('new_email.txt') as read_it:
    print(read_it.read())
```

Comment: Have you tried closing *new_email* ? E.G. `new_email.close()` after the `for` loop

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce, yep, that worked. Any chance you could point out how to better write this? It looks terribly clunky to me.

Comment: Better, use the `with` statement on the output file as well as as the input and it will be closed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first part to

```
with open('email_1.txt') as email_1:
    with open('new_email.txt', 'w') as new_email:
        for line in email_1:
            new_email.write(line.replace('apple', 'turnip'))
```

Changes are saved when you close the file stream.

Comment: Entirely correct; that said, note the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: I am familiar with these; however I shall try harder to ensure that questions are new and unique in future before answering them. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't closed `new_email`. You will either need to call `new_email.close()` or preferably put it in a with block:

```
with open('email_1.txt') as email_1:
    with open('new_email.txt', 'w') as new_email:
        for line in email_1:
            new_email.write(line.replace('apple', 'turnip'))

with open('new_email.txt') as read_it:
    print(read_it.read())
```

Comment: Entirely correct; that said, note the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".